# Magento 2 reload stock status of configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, stock-status

I've been trying to understand the "On stock" issue on the product page for a few days now.
Unfortunately, with the standard installation some things work differently than expected.

Why does the stock status not change when an attribute of a configurable product is changed?

Is this a bug of Magento or is the behaviour so intended?

How can I reload stock status each time I click on a different attribute of the configurable product, so that the current stock status of each individual product is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

When Magento 2 is not behaving as expected the best bet is clearing the cache and/or reindexing. In this case you should reindex.

> bin/magento indexer:reindex

[Magento 2 index documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#config-cli-subcommands-index-reindex)

Comment: Hey Zivorad, thanks for your answer! unfortunately it does not solve the problem. even with a newly installed magento 2.2 shop, configurable products generally do not display the correct stock status.

Comment: Is it a multi-store?

Comment: The "single store mode" is not enabled, but there is only one website, one store and one storeview. The stock status of configurable products in the newly installed shop is not updated too.

Comment: Are you changing stock inside default or website scope?

Comment: In "All Store Views"

Comment: Could you try switching to website scope, and changing there.

Comment: It doesn't change anything